# How do i cut 2 objects together

Tags: modifiers

Any idea how to cut these two objects so that i get a connected tunnel to be able to walk through? I was able to cut the A part but not the B part of the tunnel.

[image]

[image: Result from adding boolean to B part (tunnel)]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track with using the Boolean Modifier, you just have to use it on the "Lumpy Tunnel" as well.

Add a boolean to your tunnel, and select your staircase as the cut object. As you can see from the photos, the original placement of the staircase causes the bool to make some ugly cuts (Image 1), but if you move it .001 along the Y axis, it makes a cleaner bool operation (Image 2).

[image: Bool1]

[image: Bool2]

After applying the boolean, it's just a matter of cleanup. For me, the bool left a ring of duplicate faces on the inside of the "merged junction (Image 3). I deleted them, and then there was another ring of faces underneath. Select and delete them as well (Image 4).

[image: Bool3]

[image: Bool4]

The result should look like this:

[image: Bool5]

Comment: i took a one month break from Blender and now i know why. Splitting two objects should be like the easiest thing in the Solar System. Anyway. What do you mean by "move it .001 along the Y axis" ? Move the staircase 0.001 in Y? When i do that all i get is like a mark on the tunnel. Added a pic to question.

Comment: What I mean is that as you can see in my first image, the bool causes "cut lines" along the edge of the staircase. If you move the staircase object (G + Y + .001), the bool no longer causes these cuts. I found problems with the subtraction operation unless I made this adjustment.

Comment: If it ends up being a bit different on your end, that's ok, just make sure the positioning of the objects results in a "clean cut" (blender has to do things to make a bool operation "happen". this sometimes means connecting a new edge line to a nearby vertex. This can be "helped along" by the user - One of the most common ways is by manually positioning the objects so the result of the bool operation is more optimized).